# identity frame work in asp.net entity framework mvc dont let me register an user ! why?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

Hi i tried to make my own table that represent the simple membership in identity in mvc4 and use the same security being them....

so look what i made : recreate all teh table with proprieties :

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
  {
    public UsersContext()
      : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("webpages_Membership")]
  public class Membership
  {
    public Membership()
    {
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int MemberShipId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public UserProfile UserId { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("webpages_OAuthMembership")]
  public class OAuthMembership
  {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), StringLength(30)]
    public string Provider { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), StringLength(100)]
    public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile UserId { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("webpages_Roles")]
  public class Role
  {
    public Role()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserProfile> UserId { get; set; }

  }

  [Table("UserProfile")]
  public class UserProfile
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> RoleId { get; set; }
  }
}
```

all table is created and everiting is good .... but when im oponning the prgramme and try to register it making me an error ! it saing Invalid column name 'UserId'. when i clic on the register button ... and when im looking what wrong in teh condition before .... it say websecurity.hasUserId = fasle .... and i tink it where is the probleme but im confuse dont know what cause the prob .... so ty for ur help if u can ! :D

the wierdest thing is that the user is created anyway ..... but not the membership and everyting ....

Comment: should `public UserProfile UserId { get; set; }` be  `public virtual UserProfile UserId { get; set; }` as it is a navigation property?

Comment: yeah i guess ur right but i doupt it the problem but i can try :P

Comment: well its will be a problem because its not marked as virtual so its going to try create a column for it in the `webpages_Membership` table